# How to Content Security Policy(CSP) while integrating Stripe with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, ejs

I'm currently working on integrating Stripe into my web application. I've encountered an issue related to the Content Security Policy (CSP).

I'm using Express with the ejs engine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>checkout --</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
   <script id="public-key-script" data-public-key="<%= publicKey %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/client.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Stripe App Checkout Page</h1>

    <form id="payment-form">
      <div id="card-element"></div>
      <button id="submit-button" type="button">Pay Now</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**API Route :**

```
stripeRoute.get("/checkout", isAuth, (_: Request, res: Response) => {
  const publicKey = String(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);

  return res.render("checkout", {
    publicKey,
  });
});
```

**client.js File :**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  const publicKeyScript = document.getElementById("public-key-script");
  const publicKey = publicKeyScript.getAttribute("data-public-key");ey);
  
  const stripe = Stripe(publicKey);

  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");

  submitButton.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(cardElement);

    if (error) {
      console.log("Error --> ", error);
    }

    console.log("Token --> ", token.id);
});
```

But in the console, I'm receiving the following error :

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

I think the error is occurring due to the inline public key passed in ejs which was used in the client.js file.

Also, I'm new to Stripe, so It would be great if explain to me why this CSP error occurred, and how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Here's the list of [directives](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy) that should be included in stripe.js integration if you're using CSP.

Comment: On the side note, token API, i.e. using `createToken()` is a legacy integration and no longer recommended. I'd recommend referring to the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) for the latest recommended integration